# How can I fix this invisible vertex connection/long face?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

[image]
As you can see in the picture I have some vertices that are connected but I don't see anything like that in the editor window. How can I see these faces and fix them? I'm just confused how there is some random huge face connection that I can't see in the editor window. I just selected everything and selected unwrap.

Using blender 2.9

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (the coat only): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some geometry that isn't being included in the seam.  Take a close look at the edge of the left sleeve of the jacket.  Where the long seam meets the circular seam it looks like you have a triangle, which is probably really overlapping vertices.  Fix that and your problem should go away.

Comment: While this wasn't exactly it it did lead me to finding this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3EM6GBzVsg 

Which talks about snapping vertices together. I just deleted the faces that were the issue and from the remaining edges extruded those and connected them back up to the original values. So now that weird overlapping face that I couldn't select or edit has been fixed.